# Calculate the electric potential $\Phi(\textbf{r})$ generated by a charge density $\rho(\textbf{r})$ that depends on the delta dirac function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

An electric charge density $\rho{\textbf(r)}$ generates an electric potential

$$  \Phi(r) = \int d^{3}\textbf{r}' \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{\rho(\textbf{r}')}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}'|}. $$

Calculate the potential  $\Phi(\textbf{r})$, with p,q constants, $\delta(\textbf{r})$ is the delta dirac fuction and $\delta^{(3)}(\textbf{r})= \delta(x) \delta(y) \delta(z)$ when the electric charge density is given by:

i)$\rho(\textbf{r}) = q\delta^{(3)}(\textbf{r})$,

ii)$\rho(\textbf{r}) = p\frac{d}{dz}\delta^{(3)}(\textbf{r})$.

I struggled with where to begin and how to interpret a vector argument of the delta dirac function, any leads or suggestions?

I intend on adding my attempt with an edit but I am slow with latex.

Answer (score 0):

The Dirac delta has the property that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(\mathbf{x})\delta(\mathbf{x}) d^n\mathbf{x} = f(0)$, i.e. integrating against it means evaluating the function in the integrand at zero. This should give you everything you need to solve the first part.

For the second question, try integrating by parts. To be rigorous, you'll likely want to integrate by parts over the annulus $1/N<|\mathbf{r'}-\mathbf{r}|<N$ to avoid issues at the singularity (and so you have a bounded region) and then send $N\to\infty$ to recover the original integral.

Comment: This might be it but ill do a comparison to my effort before accepting it